# Stop slideToggle from bouncing on resize

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, slidetoggle

I have a responsive menu which is hidden under 590px and that is displayed over that width.

This code works properly on $(window).ready but is lame on resize.

```
$(window).resize(function () {

if ($(window).width()  > 0 && $(window).width()  < 590){ 
$('.container').click(function() {
$( '.category' ).slideToggle();
 });
}
else if ($(window).width()  > 591){ 
$( '.category' ).show();
}
});
```

Indeed, the menu is triggered multiple times after resizing.

It seems to be a common issue but I don't know how to tackle it.

///////////// EDIT ///////////

Found a way out using .unbind to stop the bouncing. Hope it helps someone else.

```
function slideMenu(){
$( '.menu' ).slideToggle();
}


$(window).on('resize',function () {

if ($(window).width()  > 0 && $(window).width()  < 590){ 
  $('.menu').hide();
  $('.container').unbind('click', slideMenu);
  $('.container').on('click', slideMenu);
}
else if ($(window).width()  > 591){ 
  $('.menu').show();
  $('.container').off('click', slideMenu);
}
}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant css and html or better yet provide a fiddle? Your code is not really making sense, and I believe there is a better approach with media queries and a check in the handler versus what you have here.

Comment: Hi There, I found a way out. Updating my post now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't use unbind.  It's deprecated.  Use the off() method (that you are correctly using in the else statement).  I still think there's an easier way using media queries and doing the check inside of your handler...

Comment: How would you use the check I'm not aware of that function ?